# What does a static import of star from a static inner class do?

Tags: java, syntax, import, scope

I was looking at the source of [List](https://github.com/functionaljava/functionaljava/blob/634a8389b986f78a386d743d8c65e5feb32d28e0/core/src/main/java/fj/data/List.java).map in Functional Java and saw it was using some class called `Buffer`, but couldn't find the class anywhere, then I looked at the imports and realized it was an inner class. But the import line looked funny:

```
import static fj.data.List.Buffer.*;
```

What does it do? Why is it importing from itself?

Comment: It is importing all the `static` elements inside `fj.data.List.Buffer`. By doing this, you just need to call `Something` instead of `fj.data.list.Buffer.Something`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`import static fj.data.List.Buffer.*` imports all static members of `Buffer` into scope. Otherwise, all references to static members of `Buffer` within the file (except for the references made from inside `Buffer`) would need to be prefixed with `Buffer.`.

Instead of this:

`final Buffer<B> bs = Buffer.empty();`

One could write this anywhere in the file:

`final Buffer<B> bs = empty();`

Use of the wildcard could have been avoided. They could have instead wrote `import static fj.data.List.Buffer.empty` and another import for each other static member they use from `Buffer`, but it could be argued that wildcard is fine here since it's importing from the same file.

Answer (score 1):

It is importing all the `static` elements inside `fj.data.List.Buffer`. By doing this, you just need to call `Something` instead of `fj.data.list.Buffer.Something`.

More info:

- [Oracle Java Docs:Static Import](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/static-import.html)

Answer (score 0):

It means all of static fields and methods will be imported. And they can be accessed without class name prefix in importing class.